# button onclick change visibility of a class using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to change the visibility of class "feel"  and "feels" when user clicks on button "signup" using javascript but I am not getting anywhere. Nothing happens when i click on the button.
I have set visibility of class "feels" hidden at first. After user clicks on button it should change to visible and visibility of class "feel" should change to hidden.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  signup()
});

function signup() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("feel").style.visibility: "hidden";
  document.getElementsByClassName("feels").style.visibility: "visible";
}
```

```html
<div class="feel">
  <h2>Be a part of this society to feel.</h2>
  <p><a href="">Forgot your password?</a> Doesn't have an account?
    <button id="btn" onclick="return(signup());" id="sign">Signup</button>
    <form action name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
      <input type="email" required placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Sign In">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="feels">
  <h1>Please provide the following informations:</h1>
  <form action name="form" onsubmit="return(validate1());">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" name="fname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Lastname" name="lname">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Re-type Password" name="repass">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" Value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: 2 ids for button `btn` and `sign`. remove any one

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns array of elements not single element  .Your syntax is totally incorrect   Should be like this    `document.getElementsByClassName("feel")[0].style.visibility =  "hidden";`

Comment: I forgot to remove that second id. Since I am self taught, and i am pretty much on basics right now I didn't know such difference could take place taking class and id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `:` which used in Object initializer but for assigning you should use `=`.

`getElementsByClassName` return a HTMLCollection. It doesnot have property `style`. You can use `forEach()` and `querySelectorAll()`.

```
function signup()
{
   document.querySelectorAll(".feel").forEach(x => x.style.visibility = "hidden");
   document.querySelectorAll(".feels").forEach(x => x.style.visibility = "visible");
}
```

#### Working Snippet

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  signup()
});

function signup()
{
       document.querySelectorAll(".feel").forEach(x => x.style.visibility = "hidden");
       document.querySelectorAll(".feels").forEach(x => x.style.visibility = "visible");
}
```

```html
<div class="feel">
  <h2>Be a part of this society to feel.</h2>
  <p><a href="">Forgot your password?</a> Doesn't have an account?
    <button id="btn" onclick="return(signup());" id="sign">Signup</button>
    <form action name="myForm" onsubmit="return(validate());">
      <input type="email" required placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Sign In">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="feels">
  <h1>Please provide the following informations:</h1>
  <form action name="form" onsubmit="return(validate1());">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" name="fname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Lastname" name="lname">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Re-type Password" name="repass">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" Value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct. OP can also refer the running code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/3vmxzv6p2m

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Here's a [**Sample Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrg0q184/1/)

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", signup);

function signup() {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll(".feel")[0];
  var b = document.querySelectorAll(".feels")[0];
  a.style.visibility = "hidden"
  b.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: so that 0 index means the first one of class .feel and .feels right?
and why are we using addEventListener, i mean in the code i have used onclick. so i am confused about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your sign button has 2 id attributes: id="sign" and id="btn".

Then: you dont have a *function* called "return", put "return signup()" in your onclick attribute of the button.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the method getElementsByClassName returns an HTML Collection of all the occurence of that class found in the page instead of a single HTML element ( notice the 's' in getElementsByClassName which makes it plural). Therefore the compiler could not find any property style or visibility and it must have thrown an error on console, always make sure to watch console for errors when things does not work.

If you are sure that there would be only one element with that class, you should use id instead and then use getElementById method which returns a single object.

If you are sure there would be multiple element with that class make sure you know the position of the occurence of that class so that you can access it via index on HTML collection returned by getElementsByClassName

```
`document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].style.visibility="hidden"`
```

P.S you can directly attach the signup function as an event handler
    `document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", signup);`